# Conversion from LPTSTR to tstring causes runtime error

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I am attempting to convert a LPTSTR variable to tstring(ie, wstring in a unicode application and string in ANSI).

**How do I perform this conversion?**

My code attempts to perform the conversion but it causes the error: "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: invalid null pointer":

```
#ifdef UNICODE  
#define tstring std::wstring  
#else  
#define tstring std::string  
#endif 

tstring TVManager::getDevicePropertyTEST(HDEVINFO hDevInfo, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData, DWORD flag)
{
    DWORD dataT      = 0;
    DWORD buffersize = 0;
    LPTSTR buffer    = NULL;

    while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo,  &deviceInfoData, flag, &dataT,
                                             (PBYTE)buffer, buffersize, &buffersize))
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            // Change the buffer size.
            if (buffer) 
                LocalFree(buffer);
            buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, buffersize);
        }
        else {
            // Insert error handling here.
            debug_print_ex("Else happened:", buffer);
            break;
        }
    }

    tstring propertyValue = tstring(buffer); // ERROR OCCURS HERE

    if (buffer) 
        LocalFree(buffer);

    return propertyValue;
}
```

Comment: simplify things by not using the `T` stuff. the `T` stuff is about supporting Windows 9x. there is no good reason to support Windows 9x as of 2013 (and besides, if you wanted to support it then the rational way would be Layer for Unicode). also, instead of `LocalAlloc` and `LocalFree`, just use a `std::basic_string` directly as buffer. in general it's pretty silly to do "manual" dynamic allocation in modern C++, and especially when all you do with it is to copy the data to a standard library container: use that container in the first place.

Comment: also, use `typedef` rather than `#define`: avoid those pesky unintentional text substitutions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for the insight. Would it be possible to provide an example of how to use the basic_string in my function?

Comment: `string` is a typedef of `basic_string<char>`, and `wstring` is `basic_string<wchar_t>`. after getting rid of the `T` stuff you'd use `wstring`, presumably. declare it with size 1 in order to *have* a buffer at the start. get a pointe to the buffer by `&s[0]` (not relying on C++11 `data` method, and besides this is an idiom). resize by using `resize`.

Comment: By the way, there are definitely better ways to go about this, as others have mentioned, but as for your `tstring` definition alone, it would be easier just to do `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` (or `using tstring = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;` in C++11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a null pointer to `std::basic_string<>`'s constructor – no good. Assuming you just want an empty string if `buffer` is null, then do the following:

```
tstring propertyValue;
if (buffer)
    propertyValue = buffer;
```

Comment: it would be nice to explain to the OP how the whole approach is misguided, rather than (only) answer the technical about how to start the car's engine by affixing some Rube Goldberg thingy and hand-cranking